# rendering multiple elements with OpenGL not showing

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

I've been working on a simple renderer and just can't figure it out.
No problem if I render 1 cube, but after that it renders every 3rd (1st, 4th, 7th, 10th,...). If anyone has a good advice or spots something I missed, I'd really appreciate the help.

```
class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer();
    ~Renderer();

    void init();
    void addCube(Cube cube);
    void draw();
    void render();

private:
    std::vector<Cube> m_cubes; /*Class builds 12 Voxels and 36 Indices*/
    std::vector<Voxel> m_voxels;
    std::vector<GLushort> m_indices;
    GLuint m_vao;
    GLuint m_veo;
    GLuint m_vbo;
    para::TextureCache m_textureCache; /*Texture map to avoid multiple loading*/
};
/*Renderer.cpp*/
Renderer::Renderer() {
}

Renderer::~Renderer() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_veo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
}

void Renderer::init() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_veo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Voxel), (void*)offsetof(Voxel, pos));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Voxel), (void*)offsetof(Voxel, color));
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Voxel), (void*)offsetof(Voxel, uv));
}

void Renderer::addCube(Cube cube) {
        m_cubes.push_back(cube);
        int tmp = m_indices.size();
        /*loads or retrieves already mapped texture - returns GLuint*/
        m_cubes.back().texture = m_textureCache.getTexture(cube.textureName);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < cube.voxels.size(); i++) {
            m_voxels.push_back(cube.voxels[i]);
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cube.indices.size(); j++) {
            GLushort temp = cube.indices[j] + tmp;
            m_indices.push_back(temp);
        }
}

void Renderer::draw() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_voxels.size() * sizeof(Voxel), &m_voxels.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_veo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indices.size() * sizeof(GLushort), &m_indices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Renderer::render() {
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_cubes[0].texture); /*fixed value just for testing*/
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem that you could probably have identified yourself by stepping through the code in a debugger, and looking at variable values. The issue I see is that you're using the wrong value for the adjustment from "local" to "global" indices in this code fragment:

```
    int tmp = m_indices.size();
    /*loads or retrieves already mapped texture - returns GLuint*/
    m_cubes.back().texture = m_textureCache.getTexture(cube.textureName);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cube.voxels.size(); i++) {
        m_voxels.push_back(cube.voxels[i]);
    }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cube.indices.size(); j++) {
        GLushort temp = cube.indices[j] + tmp;
        m_indices.push_back(temp);
    }
```

The index values address entries in the vertex array, which in your case is named `m_voxels`. So when you add an object, to adjust the indices for vertices that are already stored from previous objects, you need to add the number of previously added *vertices* to the indices, not the number previous indices.

So the first line in that code fragment needs to be changed to:

```
    int tmp = m_voxels.size();
```

Comment: Yes I noticed it the next day I ran it. Guess I was just to tired to see it. Thanks anyway and sorry about the post.